# Invoking a call() method introduced by a trait

Tags: groovy, traits

I'm seeing a rather strange thing with the new Groovy trait implementation. I have a (single method interface) class that implements a `call()` method so I can call call its only method just like a closure: `instance()` instead of having to do `instance.call()` . However as soon as I introduce such a reference (a `Callable`) using a trait that breaks. Anyone who can give a hint if this is something that is as expected or is there a workaround to that?

```
class MethodCallSpec extends Specification {

    def "call a callable"() {
        expect:
        def thing = new Callable()
        "hello" == thing.call("hello")
    }

    def "call a callable like a closure"() {
        expect:
        def thing = new Callable()
        "hello" == thing("hello")
    }

    def "call with callable"() {
        expect:
        def thing = new SomethingWithCallable()
        "hello" == thing.doSomething("hello")
    }
}

class Callable {
    Object call(def message) {
        message
    }
}

trait WithCallable {
    Callable callable = new Callable();
}

class SomethingWithCallable implements WithCallable {
    def doSomething(def message) {
        callable(message) // this breaks unless written as callable.call(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a bug. If You change `trait` to `class` and use `extends` it also does not work.

Comment: `getCallable()(...)` works with the trait.  when moving the callable into the class itself, using `this.&callable(message)` results in the same error (also without the &).